# Inserting values in specific row sql java

Tags: java, sql

```
"SELECT * FROM PlayerClass WHERE Username = '" + p.getName() + "'"
```

So I  have selected the specific row and how would I go about inserting a value in column ExColumn in the same exact row?

Comment: see for `UPDATE` syntax

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) and [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), I would suggest you do this:

```
String sql = "UPDATE PlayerClass SET ExColumn = ? WHERE Username = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setObject(1, exColumnValue); // exColumnValue is the data you're trying to insert
ps.setString(2, p.getName());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

This way you'll be avoiding [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementation) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to   use [**UPDATE**](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-update-statement.htm)

```
"Update PlayerClass set Username = '" +someValue + "'"
```

That will update all rows

To update secific rows with some condition ,add where clause.

```
 "Update PlayerClass set Username = '" +someValue + "'
                                 WHERE Username = '" + p.getName() + "'"
```

Comment: You have a missing where clause!

Answer (score 1):

May be your are trying to update specific row. then this will help you

```
UPDATE PlayerClass SET ExColumn='YOUR_INSERTION_DATA_IN_THIS'
WHERE Username = 'XYZ'
```